# Why aren't milliseconds excluded from JSON when using dateFormat in Jackson's ObjectMapper with Java 8 dates?

Tags: java, date, kotlin, jackson, java-time

I am trying to figure out why Jackson (2.9.5) formats dates from Java 8 incorrectly.

```kotlin
data class Test(
        val zonedDateTim: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(),
        val offsetDateTim: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(),
        val date: Date = Date(),
        val localDateTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
)

val mapper = ObjectMapper().apply {
    registerModule(KotlinModule())
    registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
    dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
}

println(mapper.writeValueAsString(Test()))
```

From the date format I provided I would expect to get dates formatted without milliseconds but instead the result looks like this:

```json
{
  "zonedDateTim" : "2018-07-27T13:18:26.452+02:00",
  "offsetDateTim" : "2018-07-27T13:18:26.452+02:00",
  "date" : "2018-07-27T13:18:26",
  "localDateTime" : "2018-07-27T13:18:26.452"
}
```

Why are milliseconds being included in the formatted dates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dateFormat` only applies to `Date` objects - the 3 other objects are handled by the `JavaTimeModule`, which uses ISO formatting by default.

If you want a different format, you can use:

```
val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

val javaTimeModule = JavaTimeModule();
javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, LocalDateTimeSerializer(format));
javaTimeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, ZonedDateTimeSerializer(format));
mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
```

You may also need to add `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);` but I'm not 100% sure that it's necessary.

Also note that with that format, you will lose time zone and offset information. So you may want a different format for Offset/Zoned-DateTimes.

Comment: Did you test this yourself? Implementing your change has zero impact on the output I get. On top of it find it strange that configuring LocalDateTimeDeserializer should have any impact on ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime

Comment: @Daniel my example will only change the output for `LocalDateTime`, you need to do the same for the other two. Did it not change the output of `"localDateTime" : "2018-07-27T13:18:26.452"`?

Comment: No it didn't and as far as I can tell there is not even a default implementation for ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime available.

Comment: @Daniel Oh my bad - it should be `javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(format));`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. I've accepted it as a correct. For future readers you might want to update your answer one more time because there is no public ctor in OffsetDateTimeSerializer that takes the format as parameter.

Comment: @Daniel Indeed - how did you solve the issue? Did you write a custom serializer?

Comment: I haven't done it so far but that will be the approach I will take. Since it's more of a side project I didn't have time to work on it yet.

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557100/642706) is correct. Here are some further thoughts.

## Truncate

If you really do not want the fractional second at all, truncate to whole seconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

The formatters used by the various `toString` methods by default omit any text representing the fractional second if the value is zero.

So the value of:

> 2018-07-27T13:18:26.452+02:00

…becomes:

> 2018-07-27T13:18:26.000+02:00

…and its `String` representation will be generated as seconds without a fraction:

> 2018-07-27T13:18:26+02:00

Try it.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-07-27T13:18:26.452+02:00" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odtTrunc = odt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;

System.out.println( "odt.toString(): " + odt ) ;
System.out.println( "odtTrunc.toString(): " + odtTrunc ) ;
```

Try that [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/yRfBPw).

> odt.toString(): 2018-07-27T13:18:26.452+02:00
>
> odtTrunc.toString(): 2018-07-27T13:18:26+02:00

## Avoid legacy classes

The code in your Question confuses me. Do not mix the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat` with the modern *java.time* classes. The legacy classes are entirely supplanted by the modern ones.

## Timeline

Be clear that `LocalDateTime` serves a very different purpose than `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`. A `LocalDateTime` object purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it *cannot* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).